# Reverse Battery Protection using P-Channel MOSFET

Tags: power-supply, texas-instruments, pmos, reverse-polarity

I read the [TI document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae57a/slvae57a.pdf?ts=1626234432439&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fideal-diodes-oring-controllers%252Foverview.html) on page 5, according to this figure, when the GS of MOSFET from negative to positive the P MOSFET turned off, but why the Vout voltage will drop to minus.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks to be happening is that the Gate-Source capacitance of the PMOS is not discharged immediately. We can see that the Vgs curve has not settled yet when the input voltage crosses zero. So the Vgs > 0 for a short time after the input voltage has become begative.

Realize that any MOSFET has a certain Gate-Source capacitance. This Cgs capacitance needs to be discharged to turn the PMOS off. This discharing is not immediate as there are two resistors limiting the discharging current.

That means that the input voltage can already be negative while the PMOS is not switched off yet. The PMOS will then just conduct the negative input voltage to the output until Cgs has been discharged and Vgs becomes zero turning the PMOS off.

If you want to understand this better I suggest using a circuit simulator (for example: LTSpice) to simulate this effect.

Comment: Hi Bimpelrekki 
I know what you mean, in the datasheet it said Note that the output is completely discharged due to lack of reverse current blocking
functionality and any hold up capacitors are discharged.
DO you know what does lack of reverse current blocking functionality mean?

Comment: Because the MOSFET still turn on so the current is minus, the output capacitor discharge?

Comment: *lack of reverse current blocking* It means that the current through the PMOS can also flow in the reverse direction, here from Vout (=output) back to Vbat (= input). So when the input voltage drops and/or goes negative, the current flow will reverse so the capacitor between Vout and ground will be discharged.

Comment: I got it. thanks for your help.